# Angular.js md-autocomplete does not work

Tags: angularjs, autocomplete, material-design

Does anyone else know why?

```
<md-autocomplete md-selected-item="selectedItem" md-search-text="searchText" md-items="item in getMatches(searchText)" md-item-text="display" placeholder="Search...">
    <span md-highlight-text="searchText">{{item.display}}</span>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Nothing shows up.

Comment: add the code from your controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's necessary to do:
bower install angular-material#master

Not available with:
bower install angular-material